# How To Import Database in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I exported My Entire database from windows.
Now I want to Import my entire database in ubuntu 14.04.
How can i do that??
Can anyone suggest me??

I have apache & mysql installed
I had installed PHPmyadmin but its not working 
So,I had installed MySQL workbench too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use phpmyadmin, to install it if you havn't yet

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

then you can use the web interface, of course I assume you have apache & mysql installed

Answer (score 3):

You can import your database in several ways:

Using MySQL client:

- Log into your database:

  mysql -u username -p
- Once you are login select your database:

  mysql> use DATABASE
- After that import your database:

  source import.sql

(Another way is as @Karlis says)

Using MySQL Workbench:

- Just load the program, select your database (double click), load your dump script and select *Run Script*

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql
```

Comment: It would be great to provide more details